# Rails instance variables display in development but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, instance-variables

I am creating an app with Rails 4.2.3 and Postgres database in development and production, deploying to Heroku. Both my dev and production environment are seeded with the same data.

I have three tables - Cities, Neighborhoods, Venues.

```
class Venues < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :neighborhood
end
class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :venues
end
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :neighborhoods
end
```

On the app/views/neighborhoods/show.html.erb page I want to display the Venues that belong to that neighborhood.

The app/controllers/neighborhoods_controller.rb show action is this:

```
def show
  @city = City.find(params[:city_id])
  @neighborhood = @city.neighborhoods.find(params[:id])
  @venues = Venue.where(neighborhood_id: @neighborhood)
end
```

The neighborhood routes are embedded in the cities routes, but venues are a separate resource not embedded.

```
resources :cities do
  resources :neighborhoods
end
resources :venues
```

The Neighborhood show page for any particular neighborhood displays the neighborhood name, city name, then checks if there are any venues via the @venues instance variable. If so it iterates over each of them, otherwise it states there are no venues. 
app/views/neighborhoods/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @neighborhood.hood_name + ', ' + @city.city_name %></h1>
<% if @venues.present? %>
  <h3>Venues</h3>
  <% @venues.each do |venue|  %>
    <p><%= link_to venue.venue_name, venue %></p>
  <% end %>        
<% else %>
  <p>There are no venues in this neighborhood</p>
<% end %>
```

This works fine on my mac in dev mode, but when I load it to Heroku the @venues instance variable is always nil. I confirmed using irb and the console that the venues are indeed in the database on Heroku. They just aren't being recognized. Any idea how to fix this? The logs don't give any clues. From a gem perspective, beside the pg gem, in production I am using gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.3' and 'puma','~> 2.12.2'.

### Additional Information

I tried to just pass a simple instance variable from the controller to the show page for both the cities controller/show page and neighborhood controller/show page. 
app/controllers/cities_controller.rb

```
    def show
      @hellocity = "Hello from the show action in the cities controller."
    end
```

app/controllers/neighborhoods_controller.rb

```
    def show
      @hellohood = "Hello from the show action in the neighborhoods controller."
    end
```

Then in the views I called each:
app/views/cities/show.html.erb
    `<%= @hellocity %>`

app/views/neighborhoods/show.html.erb
    `<%= @hellohood %>`

The result is in my development environment when I go to any city page I get the hellocity message and when I go to any neighborhood page I get the hellohood message. But when I put this on Heroku I only get the message on the city page. The instance variable is not getting passed to the app/views/neighborhoods/show.html.erb page. @neighborhoods and @cities are being passed but anything else (e.g., @hellohood or @venues) is being blocked. Very strange.

Comment: what do you get on heroku when you do `<h1><%= @neighborhood.id %></h1>`

Comment: Do you have the same data on development that you have on Heroku?

Comment: Q: what do you get on heroku when you do <h1><%= @neighborhood.id %></h1>? A: That works fine in both development and production. So if the neighborhood_id is 12 this will display 12.

Comment: I do have the same data in both the dev and production environment.

Comment: Try putting `pry` into the view - that should let you know what is going on.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Ruby on Heroku and locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Result:** I was able to resolve this by resetting the Postgres Database on Heroku. I dropped the neighborhood table by running a migration.
`rails generate migration DropNeighborhoodsTable`

Then populating the migration file:

```
class DropNeighborhoodsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :neighborhoods
  end
  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Then migrate the database on Heroku:
`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Then I regenerated the neighborhood model/table, then reseeded the data. But I had to do this process several times before it worked. And the final time I reduced the cities table from containing all cities in the US (~30,000) to just local ones (~100). So maybe the problem was that I am currently using the free tier on Heroku and that was just too much data so it was choking it somehow. Honestly I don't know. But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to be sure you have that data in your Heroku DataBase.

I would recommend to run rails console on heroku and debug your data step by step. You do know `city_id` and `neighborhood_id` from `params[:city_id]` and `params[:id]`.

Simply run these lines one by one and check the result of each:

```
city = City.find(params[:city_id]) # does city exists?
neighborhood = city.neighborhoods.find(params[:id]) # does it have neighbors?
venues = Venue.where(neighborhood_id: neighborhood) # do you have venues?
```

I'm pretty sure you will find missing data.

Actually you just need to check if you have venues for that neighbourhood id. If you haven't faced "Page not found" error then your `City` and `Neighborhood` already exists.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above lines in the Heroku command line interface and it does work. I mean the city and neighborhoods work in the browser already. But in the CLI the venues that I expected to see for a given neighborhood are showing up when I run the last line venues = Venue.where(neighborhood_id: neighborhood). So it is indeed in the database. And it is also showing up in the browser when run on my localhost. Just for some reason it's not working on Heroku.